# Hide add to cart based on cart items

Tags: magento2, product, cart, basket

I need to be able to hide the add to cart button of certain products are already in the cart.

I have Full Page Cache turned on so it seems to cant access the checkout session.

What would be the best approach to take on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you tell me more about your requirements? Does it really need to be hidden? I'm asking because there can be a better, more UX friendly solution for that.

Now I can only say that you are right about FPC (Full Page Cache).

You have to use javascript to get user private data.
Please look into files from Magento_Catalog module:

- `addtocart.phtml`
- `validate-product.js`

You see that by default add to cart button is disabled and then when `validate-product.js` is triggered it makes button enabled.

What you could is to hide this button by default (css class, etc.) and show it only if specific product hasn't been already added to cart.

How to extend `validate-product.js` widget https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_mixins.html#extend-jquery-widget

How to check if product is already in cart?

When extending `validate-product.js` you can use `Magento_Customer/js/customer-data` to get information about items in cart.

Example how you can use `customer-data` in some other js module.

```
define([
    'someOtherDependency1'
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'someOtherDepedency2'
], function (dep1, customerData, otherDep2) {
    'use strict';

    // some code

    // get cart items
    var cartData = customerData.get('cart'),
      items = cartData().items;

    // subscribe for cart data changes
    cartData.subscribe(function (updatedCart) {
      
    }

    // rest of code
});
```

Let me know if that is enough or you will need more guidance on that. I recommend also to look into core code of Magento and look for `cartData` or `.get('cart')` so you can find examples and learn.

Comment: Thanks for this, it helped massively.